# Replacing left side of iterator from auto to pair

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to modify the code from http://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/simple-observer-pattern-implementation-c11/

I have added one more parameter to registerObserver:

```
void registerObserver( Event&& event, Observer&& observer, 
                       std::string identifier )
```

Then the map is now

```
std::map<Event, ObserverPair>
```

where

```
typedef std::pair< std::string, 
                   std::vector< std::function<void( )> > > ObserverPair;
```

However, now I don't know how to change this line correctly:

```
for (const auto& obs : observers_.at(event)) obs();
```

How can I replace this to call the second element from the pair? Since the observer is now there.

Edit:

Ok, it may be the best solution (pointed out in comments bellow) to not have a identifier and just use the reference to observer to delete it from the vector. I've created this function:

```
template <typename Observer>
void removeObserver( Event&& event, Observer&& observer )
{
  observers_[std::move( event )]
    .erase( std::remove(  observers_[event].begin( ),
                          observers_[event].end( ),
                          std::forward<Observer>( observer ) ), 
            observers_[event].end( ) );
}
```

but then I get an error when I call with "input->removeObserver( "test", std::bind( bar ) );"

This is the error:

```
Error   1   error C2679: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::_Bind<true,void,void (__cdecl *const )(void),>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: _'Since the observer is now there.'_ Sounds like a _pun intended_ ;) ...

Comment: Do you know the difference between &&-references and &-references, and how universal references work?

Comment: Aside: What do you use the identifier for?

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't know the difference =/ I use the identifier to remove observers. The way it is (link on original post) I can't remove observers when I want to.

Comment: You should probably let the `Subject` chose the identifier, and return it. Also, an integral type may be a better idea than a string.

Comment: @YuriA.Brito: In which case you would need a mapping of observer to identifier. Why not instead pass the observer cast to `void*`? That's a unique value you get for free. So, you give it "event, callable object/function, actual object behind the callable". For the references question, search for move semantics and universal references.

Comment: @Deduplicator This is a part of a renderer. So, for example, my scene has a current_camera that can be moved around by my Input class (Input is the Subject). However, I want to be able to change the current_camera without the old current_camera having knowledge that it is not the one that can be moved now. Without mapping calls to identifiers, I don't know how to do this.

Comment: So, your change is allowing the removal of any observer. For that, you need some strong identifier, like your string, right. I just propose you use the actual observer itself, cast to `void*` to get a unique opaque id without any contaminating type information.

Comment: @Deduplicator I just edited the original post about your suggestion. =)

Comment: I don't think that would work. The observers don't have any identity. They can get copied around as the vector grows, for instance.

Comment: FWIW, I might implement an de-registration mechanism sometime soon. I just didn't get around it because I haven't needed it yet.

Comment: When someone solves your original question, do not change the question.

Comment: @Yakk But the problem isn't solved. I still have no way to remove a observer. And my edit is also wrong, because as juanchopanza pointed out, it won't work. I'm back to trying to iterate over pairs on a map.

Comment: @yuria. That is a different problem.  Do not shoe horn every issue into a question.  "rewrite thos code for me" is also a poor question: linking the code for context is ok, but make questions specific as possible, and word them so **others** can also find them and learn from them.

Answer (score 2):

`observers_.at(event)` now gives you a pair instead of a vector. The vector is the second element of the pair, so you should replace `observers_.at(event)` with `observers_.at(event).second` to access it:

```
for (const auto& obs : observers_.at(event).second) obs();
```

Comment: Actually, instead of being a vector of void functions it is now a vector of pairs. So I think this won't solve the problem =/ But thanks though.

Comment: @YuriA.Brito If it is a vector of pairs, then my deleted solution would have worked. But we must answer the question you posted, not some other one!

Answer (score 0):

These are the changes you should make to add the ability of removing an observer, uncoupling the observer as much as possible:

```
template <class Callable>
void registerObserver(const Event& event,
    Callable&& callback, const void* tag = &callback)
```

I removed move semantics from `event`, because you neither want nor need them there.
Please observe that the callback is a universal reference.
I changed the identifier/tag to a `void*` and added a default for the case that the callback is the tag.
**Use:**
- `event`: The event you want to register for.
- `callback`: The callable for notification. Explicitly use `std::move` if it is ephemeral.
- `tag`: The observer object notified or some other good tag. Defaults to `callback` for the case that the observer-object is the same.

```
void removeObserver( const Event& event, void* vp)
{
    observers_[event].remove_if(
        [](ObserverPair& x){return x.second == vp});
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting this error now:

Error 1 error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::function<void (void)>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: The observers have no identity. They may be copied into the map, copied around internally, so attempting to take their address won't work.

Comment: @juanchopanza: They observe "for some object", which most certainly has an identity, if they aren't that object themselves and thus have an identity.

Comment: No, they don't have identity, what they do is determined by their value. You can register pretty much anything as long as it is callable without arguments.

Comment: @juanchopanza: You mean they don't need to have an identity. It depends is a great answer. Shall I elaborate?

Comment: OK, you can't rely on them having an identity.

Comment: @juanchopanza: For which reason the callback can be overridden as the tag.